# Run-time error '1004' Sorry we couldnt find.... file path. Possible moved, renamed or deleted

Tags: excel, vba

What am I doing wrong?? I've simplified this code to copy and paste a range of data from one workbook to another. But I am getting a File Path error message??

I have searched online, but still struggling to find the solution. Any help is great. Cheers!

```
 Sub GetDataFromGA3()

     Dim wbTarget As Workbook 'where the data will be pasted
     Dim wbSource As Workbook 'where the data will be copied
     Dim StrName As String 'name of the source sheet

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'these two statements help     performance by disabling the self titled in each
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook 'set to the current workbook
     StrName = ActiveSheet.Name 'get active sheetname of workbook

     Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\Test File\metrics list" & "\") 'open source workbook

     Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\Weekly logbook 2016" & "\") 'open target workbook

     wbSource.Range("A1:E60").Copy 'copy range from sourcebook

     wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("D1:H60").PasteSpecial

     wbTarget.Save ' save workbook

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: try using this slash: `/`   also, your filepath is not pointing towards a file. if your file is called metrics list, then your path needs to be `..... /test file/metrics list.xlsx" (or other file ending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

**1. File path incorrect**

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\Test FIle\metrics list" & "\") 'open source workbook

Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\Weekly logbook 2016" & "\") 'open target workbook
```

Should be someting like:

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\Test FIle\metrics list.xlsx") 'enter appropriate file extension

Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\Weekly logbook 2016.xlsx") 'enter appropriate file extension
```

**2. Sheet name missing**

```
wbSource.Range("A1:E60").Copy 'copy range from sourcebook
```

should be:

```
wbSource.Sheets("Sheet_Name").Range("A1:E60").Copy 'enter appropriate sheet name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this slash: `/`

Also, your filepath is not pointing towards a file. If your file is called "metrics list", then your path needs to be

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/jjordan/Desktop/Test Dir/Test File/metrics list.xlsx"
```

(or other file ending)

Comment: Thanks. I have made the corrections and there is now no Error. However, the data is not copying.... Or it is copying but pasting blank data.

Comment: try `wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("D1:H60").Value = wbSource.Range("A1:E60").Value` instead of your to copy paste lines.

Comment: But data doesnt copy and paste. Just shows blank Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook 'set to the current workbook StrName = ActiveSheet.Name 'get active sheetname of workbook Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\Test File\metrics list.xlsx") 'opens Target workbook Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\Weekly logbook 2016.xlsm") 'opens Source workbook

Comment: can you post an update in your question with your current code, as it is now?